# flutter Ffirebase Query returns bad state when there is no document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am streaming using StreamBuilder. And it's possible that data might not exist. So I want that if data does not exist, it should return something like `SizedBox()`.

When document has data, I see what I want to see, but when it does not have data it's giving me:

> Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("myCollection")
      .doc(uid)
      .snapshots(),
   builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot)
      {
       //I tried this
       if (!snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return const SizedBox(); }

      //I also tried this 
     if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const SizedBox();}

      //Also this
     if(!snapshot.data.exist)
      {return const SizedBox();}

      //Also after all the logics I returned else
       else {return const SizedBox();}
      }
  )
```

But none of these seems to work. It keeps returning bad state with the red screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("myCollection")
  .doc(uid)
  .snapshots(),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  // While the snapshot is in the waiting state, you can return a loading 
//indicator or another widget.
  return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Example loading indicator.
}

if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
  // If there's no data or the document doesn't exist, return a SizedBox() 
//or another widget.
  return SizedBox();
}

// You have data, and the document exists. You can access and use 
// snapshot.data here.
return YourWidgetToShowData(snapshot.data);
},
)
```

Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist. This error is occuring because you are trying to access a field on a documentSnapShot that doesn't exist,and this happens when the document is not found in the firestore collection.

This might help.